# Why chart doesn't appear on my website html

Tags: html

So I have 2 menu, both of that menu contain chart, this is my syntax for my chart

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<body>

  <h1>My Web Page</h1>

  <div id="piechart"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Load google charts
    google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['corechart']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    // Draw the chart and set the chart values
    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
        ['awwa', 8],
        ['aww', 2],
        ['TV', 4],
        ['Gym', 2],
        ['Sleep', 8]
      ]);

      // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
      var options = {
        'title': 'My Average Day',
        'width': 550,
        'height': 400
      };

      // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

But idk why when I fill the other menu with this syntax, the chart move in my new menu (it should be 2 chart in 2 menu, but why just only 1 menu and move from the old menu to my another menu who has the same syntax

Comment: because this code creates a chart for one element and you should init that for other elements to have 2 or more of than

Comment: do you know how so i can insert more than 1 chart in many menu

Comment: which part of that syntax should i change or add

Comment: but unfortunately I didn't find any code in you snippet to create a menu. please share your completed code then I can help you better

Comment: basically for this case you need a loop to render init function for all elements and holder tags!

Comment: i dont understand with your explanation (because im new in html) idk what is render init function, are you have suggestion what can i develop so this case solved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205727/discussion-between-fachry-dzaky-al-qadri-sabil-and-alex).

Comment: can you try creating a demo to reproduce the issue ?

Comment: idk how to make a single demo, do you know how?